# Is onPartitonsAssigned called when listener.resumePartiton() is called?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka

I was going through spring-kafka 2.7.0. I have a use case where I want to resume some partitions. And after they are resumed I want to seek their offsets. I was wondering when I resume, will onPartitionsAssigned be called?

If not, is there another callback?

Answer (score 0):

When a partition is resumed (after requesting a resume via that method), the container publishes a `ConsumerPartitionResumedEvent`; you can capture these events using an `@EventListener` method or an `ApplicationListener<ConsumerPartitionResumedEvent>` bean.

The event does not provide direct access to the `Consumer` so you need to perform the seeks on the `ConsumerSeekAware` callback implemented by your listener. The easiest way to do that is have your listener extend `AbstractConsumerSeekAware`.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#seek